# Remove img's from list items with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, list

I have a unordered list with list items that contain images. I'm trying to copy this list to a modal window but would like to remove the images in the modal version of the list.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="uk-networks" class="networks">
 <h7 class="catergory orange-text center">UK</h7>

 <a class="network-a" href="#"><li id="bbc"><img class="network-img" src="img/bbc.png"></li></a>
 <a class="network-a" href="#"><li id="daily"><img class="network-img" src="img/daily.png"></li></a>
 <a class="network-a" href="#"><li id="guardian"><img class="network-img" src="img/guardian.png"></li></a>
 <a  class="network-a" href="#"><li id="mirror"><img class="network-img" src="img/mirror.png"></li></a>
 <a  class="network-a" href="#"><li id="indep"><img class="network-img" src="img/indep.png"></li></a>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you use jquery?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('li img').forEach((img) => img.remove());`

Comment: use $( "img" ).remove(); its remove all img tags

Comment: @JayHarris This worked great, thanks!

Comment: @KaneCodes no problem

Answer (score 0):

**USING JQUERY**

You can loop over all the `li` elements with `img` and remove that. Keep that code in a function block so that you can call that function when your modal is displayed. To check the snippet below you need to use `inspect element` of browser in that list. Then you will see that there is no `img` tag in the list.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function removeImage(){
    $('#uk-networks li img').each(function(){
      $(this).remove();
    });
  }
  //call this function when model is displayed
  removeImage();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="uk-networks" class="networks">
 <h7 class="catergory orange-text center">UK</h7>

 <a class="network-a" href="#"><li id="bbc"><img class="network-img" src="img/bbc.png"></li></a>
 <a class="network-a" href="#"><li id="daily"><img class="network-img" src="img/daily.png"></li></a>
 <a class="network-a" href="#"><li id="guardian"><img class="network-img" src="img/guardian.png"></li></a>
 <a  class="network-a" href="#"><li id="mirror"><img class="network-img" src="img/mirror.png"></li></a>
 <a  class="network-a" href="#"><li id="indep"><img class="network-img" src="img/indep.png"></li></a>
</ul>
```

**USING JAVASCRIPT**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li img').forEach((img) => img.remove());
```

```html
<ul id="uk-networks" class="networks">
 <h7 class="catergory orange-text center">UK</h7>

 <a class="network-a" href="#"><li id="bbc"><img class="network-img" src="img/bbc.png"></li></a>
 <a class="network-a" href="#"><li id="daily"><img class="network-img" src="img/daily.png"></li></a>
 <a class="network-a" href="#"><li id="guardian"><img class="network-img" src="img/guardian.png"></li></a>
 <a  class="network-a" href="#"><li id="mirror"><img class="network-img" src="img/mirror.png"></li></a>
 <a  class="network-a" href="#"><li id="indep"><img class="network-img" src="img/indep.png"></li></a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Question doesn't tag jQuery

Comment: @JayHarris edited answer and I would also like to give credit to you on that.

Comment: It's annoying searching for JavaScript questions in 2018 and still getting JQuery when the question doesn't tag it. lol

Answer (score -1):

- ### Jquery:

  `$("a").children().children().remove();

   $("a > li >img").remove()`

Comment: Question doesn't tag jQuery

Comment: as you can see i answered about jquery usage but did not receive answer yet so maybe he is using bruh

Answer (score -1):

Using **javascript** we can do it like

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.network-img'),function(e){
  e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
});
```

Using **Jquery** All the images has a same class so following code will do the removal process.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   $('.network-img').remove();
});
```

Comment: This is a JavaScript question! ;)